# When opening the keyboard with adjust resize, how do you scroll the view to the current edittext that is focused?

Tags: android

I have an issue where on small devices, some content gets cut off when the keyboard is open. To mitigate that, we added the adjust resize soft input mode. This scrolls the view up nicely and the user can then scroll that view up and down.

However, when they click next on the keyboard, another edit text is given focus but it does not scroll the newly selected edit text to the top to be focused.

How do I make it scroll the currently focused edit text to the top of the layout?